# NSUserDefaults intitial setup

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm saving a few user settings in `NSUserDefaults`. If these settings have not been modified by the user, I'd like the app to use presets.

How should I set this up so the app first checks if settings have been modified and if not, sets presets?

Checking if `[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults]objectForKey: @"setting1"] == nil` ? Then setting a preset if it is not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDDCDB

Call that from your `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method that sets up whatever defaults you may need.

Comment: +1 @Alex can you give an example, How do use defaults elsewhere in code ?

Comment: @MSK Um, well, you use it the same way anywhere... It just makes the most sense in your app launching code.  All this method does is sets in memory some values to use when no value exists for a key you are looking up.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the NSUserDefaults docs for registerDefaults.  This allows you to have default values until the user changes them, then they have no effect.